# What do the arrows mean in the IDEA git log screen?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

After a very tricky merge we now have to enter commit messages on merge and I noticed the down/up arrows in the git/log screen for IDEA.

I think it is "disconnected" but how do I reconnect it with the remote branch?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out the arrow is just a collapse feature!  I feel silly now, but I couldn't find anything on this.

It's just a side effect from merging a lot of remotes into a single repo.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's just a navigate button to your last or next commit.
Usually, it appear when too many commits on other branch, and your last commit are too far away from current.

Answer (score 3):

The arrows are a more compact way of showing a branch that has many commits between it (exactly as @Thomas Beauvais said). This can be disabled by toggling the 'Long Edges' option (as @herui pointed out, I'm just adding a screenshot).

Click the eye icon in the git log panel to toggle it on or off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The arrow makes you easy navigate to next/previous commit of current branch
if you turn on *show long edges*, following the arrow direction on the edge, you can also navigate to next/previuos commit, but you have to scoll many screens.

Comment: Where do you turn on show long edges? You might want to describe the steps and state which version of PHPStorm you're using (and maybe which operating system it's running on).